# Why do decorator droids just dissapear when sent to a level?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I was able to complete the Christmas event without a single problem, putting aside the fact that the decorated levels reset a couple of times, but I was able to get all the rewards. This week a similar event got started, but I am not able to get any levels decorated. I summoned the free decorator droid and sent it to one of my levels (Workout Center), left the elevator, but never got "inside" the store, nor I got a animation like I got every time I  decorated a level on the Christmas event. I got another droid and I sent it to the same level, with similar results. Then, I left the game for a while, and when I played again, my Workout Center was decorated, but with no notification or anything.

And I can't decorate any other levels. I have tried with 4 or 5 levels, even sending two decorator droids to the same level as I did with Workout Center, with no results. I even did a backup of my TDS on Facebook and reinstalled the app, but the results were the same (my TDS got even worse, because now I have a lot of levels with the generic background). Does anybody have this same problem or know how to solve it?

EDIT: Additional information: I'm playing with version 1.4.1 of Tiny Death Star, on Android 4.4.2 (KitKat). My device is a Nexus 7 (2013).

2ND EDIT: Added screenshots from the Spanish version of the game. [image][image]

3RD EDIT: I haven't received an answer from tech support, but it is fixed now. I saw a decorator droid coming, but was not the Christmas one, it was R2-Q5 instead. I stored it on Arrivals and closed the game. When I opened it, everything was fixed, even the levels with generic backgrounds I had. The only thing I did was connect my device to another Wi-Fi signal instead of my home's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm playing on an iPhone 5s so my answer may not apply to your situation.

What I can only suggest is that you update your version of TDS to the latest version, and after that to force quit the app, and restart the app.

Also, if you did complete the last event and had gotten your limited edition characters like R2-Q5, you may have mistakenly think that the random appearance of R2-Q5 is an Imperial Decorator Droid when it's just another normal random appearance. Hence, when you send this R2-Q5 to a floor, it wouldn't decorate the floor. It would just scuttle off, like all other random characters with a "?".

To distinguish whether it's a Decorator Droid, you would see the Imperial icon on the bottom left of the screen when it appears. So do be on the look-out to see if the black R2 unit you get on your elevator is a "?" character or one with an Imperial icon. And if it IS one that appears together with an Imperial icon, but do not decorate your floors (it doesn't decorate those floors still under construction), then you should seek the help of technical support.

Not related to your question but a helpful observation: Decorator droids for this event seems much harder to come by. I only have 3 or maximum 4 random Decorator Droids (and that's including the 1st one which can be summoned for free) in my game so far. I finished the last 2 events quite easily, but I have had to use bux to summon 28-29 Decorator Droids this time round (which may be the devs' design to get us to spend bux, what with the recent Salvage Droids update etc).

[image: Imperial Icon]

**Decorator Droid**
[image: Decorator Droid]

**R2-Q5**
[image: Limited Edition Characters]

[image: R2-Q5]

Comment: Thank you so much for your very detailed explanation. However, something is bugging me: in my version of TDS, the decorations are quite different. I have the arrivals and Workout Center levels decorated with 9 triangle-shaped flags of different colours. And the droid is different too: it's not R2-Q5, but the same droid as in the Christmas event. I'll add some screenshots to the question to show what I mean. Maybe the events are different on iOS and Android? Although that doesn't make much sense...

Comment: Perhaps only other Android TDS players can answer you now. But from your screen shots, that decorator droid looks like the one from the Christmas event. Could your file be corrupted? I can't recall the kind of decoration for the last event (before this one) but the flags on your decorated floor looks quite familiar too.

Comment: The decorations for the Christmas event were little red and green Christmas lights, if I recall correctly. But I agree with you, maybe my save file is corrupted. I think I'm gonna reinstall the game (again) and not restore my save file, in order to check if with a new file I get the same event or the one you have. I'll add a comment with the results.

Comment: It is not a problem with my save file. I have erased the cache and data for TDS, uninstalled, and then reinstalled from the Play Store, went through the tutorial, and I have now the exact same event with the exact same problem (I summoned the free decorator droid). Any clues?

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas here too. Best to get in touch with technical support if you don't want to miss this event because I think I only have 7 days left on this event on my game. May the force be with you!

Comment: Thank you very much for your ideas and help. I have even tried to downgrade the app to 1.4.0, the version before the event, but I get the exact same event too. I'll try sending an email to technical support like you proposed. I'll post when I have an answer.

Comment: While I was waiting for tech support to send a reply, it solved itself. I saw the icon for a decorator droid, but the droid was R2-Q5 instead of the Christmas one. I closed the game and opened it again, and everything had changed; the decorator droids I had on Arrivals, the event icon, and even the levels with generic background were fixed. The only thing I did was connect to another Wi-Fi signal, if that can change anything. Thank you for your suppport!

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. Now you'll have to summon those decorator droids using bux or else you'll never get 60 before the event ends.

Comment: Received an answer from tech support. Their solution was to force close the app, restart my device, connect to a different WiFi network, and start the app again. It seems that connecting to another WiFi signal solves problems. Now I just have to get bux to finish the event!

Comment: For all you know, the tech support may just be referring to this thread! Lol

Comment: It's possible, because I sent them the link to this thread in order to give them more details on my problem! I'd like to know why these things happen... on the last event, I also got some problems, like most of the new text substituted with "???", and also got fixed by connecting to a different network.